# Regular expression to match "select...from...where" sql queries

Tags: regex

I want to find a sequence of "select from where " in a string. For example,

```
"select * from T WHERE t.c1 =1"
```

should be matched.

Here is the regular expression pattern I wrote:

```
"SELECT\s\.*FROM\s\.*WHERE\s\.*";
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't have backslash-escaped the dots; since you did, the engine is trying to match a literal dot, not "any character" like you're expecting.

Try:

```
SELECT\s.*FROM\s.*WHERE\s.*
```

Also, as others have posted, make sure it's in case-insensitive mode. How you do that depends on the language you're using.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what regex engine you're targeting, but you might try this:

```
# note the trailing i, which in perl means case-insensitive
# this will also put the interesting bits into regex backreferences
#
# This also changes \s to \s+ in case you have a situation with multiple
# spaces between terms
#
/select\s+(.*)\s+from\s+(.*)\s+where\s+(.*)/i
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the RE is that it's case sensitive. Depending on the form of RE, there is probably a flag to specify case insensitive matching. For example, Perl-compatible REs use a "/i" flag: `/SELECT\s.*FROM\s.*WHERE\s.*/i`

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- Your sql statement will not span across lines.
- You will not have two sql statements on a single line.

This works for me.

```
SELECT\s+?[^\s]+?\s+?FROM\s+?[^\s]+?\s+?WHERE.*
```

Java escaped version:

```
String regex = "SELECT\\s+?[^\\s]+?\\s+?FROM\\s+?[^\\s]+?\\s+?WHERE.*";
```

You may append a terminator instead of the .* depending on your case. Of course, you have to run it in case-insensitive mode, OR modify the regex appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, I tried to be a bit more restrictive with table and column names and also consider using filter with (=, <=,> =, <,> and IN ()):

```
string regex = "SELECT\W(([a-zA-z0-9]+)([,]*)\W)+\WFROM\W([a-zA-z0-9#]+)(\W[a-zA-Z])*\WWHERE\W([a-zA-z0-9_]+)\W([=<>IN(]+)\W(.+)"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Our community likes answers that not only show what should be done but also why. It would be great if you could expand your answer so that others can learn from your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

This response checks for comma in the fields listed, as well as characters near the WHERE condition

```
SELECT\s+(\w+)\s*((,\s*\w+\s*)*)\s+FROM\s+\w+\s+WHERE\s+\w+\s*(<|>|<>|<=|>=|=)\s*[+-]?\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your guys's reply.  I got the answer from mmyers, here is my final solution:

```
        string szPattern = @"SELECT\s.*FROM\s.*WHERE\s.*";
        Regex  rRegEX = new Regex ( szPattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline );
        Match match =rRegEX.Match(testCase.Statement);
        if (match.Success)
```